How to set up Caching with ktor
Hi i am trying to set up caching for my ktor server. It also uses ktor client to make requests to some urls to fetch json files. I wanted to use In-Memory caching for the client but it does not seem to work. When i make a request it tells me that it is caching the response for the url. However follow up requests are not faster because it always outputs
"Cached response is stale for ... should validate cached response".
My HttpClient i use for making requests currently looks like this:
object HttpClient {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })
        }
        install(HttpCache)
        install(HttpTimeout)
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.HEADERS
            sanitizeHeader { header -> header == HttpHeaders.Authorization }
        }
    }
}

and then i just make requests like this:
val response: List<myDataClass> = client.get(someUrl).body()

I also tried persistent caching. It actually stores something in the folder i defined but again, follow up requests are always stale no matter what

Can you share the response from the server that you're trying to cache?

@AlekseiTirman sorry for my late answer. Well the responses are just jsons without any additional informations. The format is not really the issue. you can take any example you want like {"id" : 1, "name" : hi}

I mean the headers returned from the server. They determine if the caching would work.

@AlekseiTirman oh sorry, here are the headers:
Headers [Date=[Sat, 15 Jun 2024 02:17:47 GMT], Server=[Apache], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Access-Control-Allow-Headers=[Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization], Access-Control-Request-Headers=[Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept], Connection=[close], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Content-Type=[application/json]]

The HttpCache plugin works according to the specification https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234. Generally, the server must return the 2** status code with the appropriate caching headers and then with the 304 status code to make the client return the cached response.

@AlekseiTirman We dont have the option to recive those caching headers from the external server. That is why i wanted to know how to handle this myself by hand by just setting up something like "save this response for x minutes". I gave up on HttpCache and now just run a function on a schedule that saves the responses as a json and update it every X minutes . But this is not a nice solution
